# How do I iterate through shapefile attribute tables and write results to a new .csv table in R?

Tags: r, arcgis, shapefile

I would like to loop through an attribute table (e.g. INPUT), determine the minimum distance there is an interaction, and write that distance plus the FID to a new table (e.g. OUTPUT). I have exported the attribute table from ArcGIS as a .csv for simplicity.

Here is some simplified example data
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxEkA.png

For example, for FID 001 there was no interaction, for 002 the interaction was at 5000 m, for 003 there was an interaction at 2000 m, and for 004 there was an interaction at 0 m.

I have the logic figured out, but I am having difficulty writing the output to a table. This is what I have come up with so far (I'm just using print here for troubleshooting purposes):

```
# Process rows and determine the minimum zone of influence
for (i in 1:nrow(INPUT)){
  ifelse(INPUT$BUFFER_0k[i]>0, print("0"), 
         ifelse(INPUT$BUFFER_2k[i]>0, print("2000"), 
                ifelse(INPUT$BUFFER_5k[i]>0, print("5000"), print("NA"))))
```

I have tried replacing print with things like

```
csvFile="C:\\...\\output.csv"
write.csv(c(INPUT$FID[i], "0"), file=csvFile, append=TRUE)
```

and I cannot even get something like the following to work in place of a simple print statement

```
print(c(INPUT$FID[i]>0, "0"))
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The logic is unclear to me. How do you figure out where the interaction was?

Comment: If the value is greater than 0, two features have intersected, and the FID of the intersecting feature is stored instead of 0.

Comment: That’s not what your example output shows. It shows some intersection distances, and it shows them for *every* FID (although yes, it may be NA). My question is: how do you calculate these distances?

Comment: The distance is determined by which buffer around the object is intersected (5000 m, 2000 m, or 0 m). So, if the intersection happens at only BUFFER_5k, I would like to output the distance 5000 to the output file. If the intersection occurs at the 2000 m buffer and 5000 m buffer, I am only interested in the 2000 m buffer

Comment: I am happy to change my logic if you have a better suggestion... I am new to R, and relatively new to programming in general

Comment: Sorry, I was just daft. The logic probably does need changing but I don’t actually see a better way now. The loop, however, needs to go. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses `print` which immediately prints the values – that’s not what you want. You want to separately (a) calculate the result and (b) write the result table into a file.

First, here’s a function which transforms a single row:

```
get_dist = function (row) {
    index = which(row > 0)[1]
    if (is.na(index)) NA else switch(index, 0, 2000, 5000)
}
```

It works by looking which is the first index that is >0, if any. `switch` translates that index into the distance.

Now we apply (literally) the function to the input matrix:

```
result = apply(input, 1, get_dist)
```

But this result is actually a vector:

```
result
#  001  002  003  004
#   NA 5000 2000    0
```

– we want a matrix or data frame:

```
result = data.frame(distance = result)
result
#     distance
# 001       NA
# 002     5000
# 003     2000
# 004        0
```

And now we can write it to a file:

```
write.csv(result, csv_file, append = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank-you for your help, but I'm running into a problem             > result = data.frame(distance = result)
Error in data.frame(`1` = 0, `2` = 0, `3` = 0, `4` = 0, `5` = 0, `6` = 0,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: What does your `result` look like before executing that statement? On the input you’ve shown, I get the output shown in my answer. Anything else implies that your input format is slightly different. Do note that `get_dist` relies on the fact that your input has exactly three columns.

Comment: Ah, I see! In reality, my unique identifier (FID in the example table) is going to be a combination of letters and numbers (02034, mf-302,...), not 1,2,3. Is it possible to include it in the output?  Also, what is the role of the [1] in    index = which(row > 0)[1] ?

Comment: @user3343890 The role of `[1]` is to look for the index of the *first* column whose value is ≠ 0. Regarding the row names / FIDs, that should just directly work: my code doesn’t care about the row names and just copies them over.